# Page number function is wrong in webscraper in R

Tags: html, r, if-statement, url, web-scraping

```html
library(rvest)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)


#Getting the number of Page

getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
  print(URL)
  parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
  pageNumber <- parsedDocument %>%
    html_nodes(".al-pageNumber") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as.integer()
  return(ifelse(length(pageNumber) == 0, 0, max(pageNumber)))
}

findURL <- function(year_chosen){
  if (year_chosen >= 1994) {
    noYearURL <- glue::glue("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F{year_chosen}%20TO%2012%2F31%2F{year_chosen}")
    pagesURl <- "&fl_SiteID=5275&page="
    URL <- paste(noYearURL, pagesURl, sep = "")
    # URL is working with parameter year_chosen
    firstPage <- getPageNumber(URL)
    paste(firstPage)
    
    if (firstPage == 5) {
      nextPage <- 0
      while (firstPage < nextPage | firstPage != nextPage) {
        firstPage <- nextPage
        URLwithPageNum <- paste(URL, firstPage-1, sep = "")
        nextPage <- getPageNumber(URLwithPageNum)
      }
    }else {
      print("The Year you provide is out of range, this journal only contain articles from 1994 to present")
    }
  }
}
findURL(2018)
```

The above code is a part of my webscrape. Mainly what I want to do is get the pages of all the journals given the parameter year. I believe my getPageNumber is wrong as I am only able to get the amount of pages seen from the first page instead  of getting all the pages  that are given in a year.

my main function is then incorrectly grabbing the urls based  off the pages.

I would  like to  add that the most pages I would like to grab for a year is 5

I would really appreciate any help! Thank you  in advance

Comment: Please give an example url where you think the page number function is returning the wrong number of pages and indicate what the correct number should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the page count needs to be calculated based on total results / number of results per page as sometimes pages as hidden by next. You may need to evolve this for wrong urls, or urls where no results and this is not indicated within the script tag being scraped currently (via regex). Perhaps wrap within an outer tryCatch.

```
getPageNumber <- function(URL) {
  print(URL)
  parsedDocument <- read_html(URL)
  results_per_page <- length(parsedDocument %>% html_nodes(".sr-list"))
  total_results <- parsedDocument %>%
    toString() %>%
    str_match(., 'num_results":"(.*?)"') %>% 
    .[,2] %>%
    as.integer()
  pageNumber <- tryCatch(ceiling(total_results / results_per_page), error = function(e) {1})
  return(pageNumber)
}


getPageNumber("https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?fl_SiteID=5275&rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2f01%2f2018+TO+12%2f31%2f2018&page=1")
```

Comment: I believe it still doesn't work. If you try to execute it  with the main function for a date like '2018'. You would get Error in if (firstPage == 5) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: However the page function does execute correctly so it may be the if statement in my main function. I'm honestly not too sure.

Comment: It is not the getPageNumber function as that correctly returns the page count for 2018. Unless a logic problem. It returns IIRC something like 18 as the total pages; whereas your test assume 5 max in next part?

Comment: Ultimately what I would like to do is have a main function that reads all the pages. If you were to run my main function you would want to get all the urls for that year with the URLs being different by the page number. That is how I would be scraping the document

Comment: The url are easy to generate as I think you know in that you just join the page number param onto the end of the url and loop those.

Comment: Hi  QHarr  you have been very helpful. However, this answer seems to have an error again. Do you know why this does not work anymore?

Comment: It works correctly. There are 18 pages.  Or is the problem related to when you later call this function? Can you provide a failing url.

Comment: I  am getting 0 when I try running this.  For  R studio  would there be a reason why a web scraper would work for a compile and then show errors for another compile of the same program?

Comment: I'm still confused by your if section. You have the total number of pages which, in this case is 18. Generate a list with paste0 to give you all 18 urls and loop those. No need for if statement etc.

Comment: Please share a pastebin (https://pastebin.com/) link to full code (minus personal info of course)

Comment: okay I will please just give me  a moment

Comment: I removed the if statement in the pastebin and pasted the program I am actually trying to run it for. I also removed the if statement as well

Comment: two things immediately. You are generating this url `https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2007%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2007&f_ContentType=Journal+Article&fl_SiteID=5275&page=-1` which has a minus 1. And you are using `firstPage <- nextPage` which will mean first time in while loop you will hit exit condition of  `firstPage == nextPage`

Comment: Why are you calling getPageNumber more than once? You have the total page number count after first call?

Comment: the first call gives you `numPages` (`numPages <- getPageNumber(URL)`) then you generate all urls to deal with using `pages <- paste0( 'https://academic.oup.com/dnaresearch/search-results?rg_IssuePublicationDate=01%2F01%2F2007%20TO%2012%2F31%2F2007&f_ContentType=Journal+Article&fl_SiteID=5275&page=', 1:numPages)`

Comment: okay so do u recommend removing everything between  firstPage <- getPageNumber(URL) to DNAresearch <- data.frame()?

Comment: I initially wrote that  to test out the function in my main. I'm confused where it says 1:nuPages?  What do you mean by that?

Comment: Also in  my R studio the output I get for getpageNumber is 0 and  I'm confused as to why that's the  case. If you are saying  the function works for you

Comment: for your code, getPageNumber returns 2. Which seems correct. I am not sure why you get 0. Did you add a print statement after `firstPage  <- getPageNumber(URL)` ? In my earlier comment I was pointing out that you are actually calculating number of pages total (numPages) rather than firstPage. So, knowing there are 2 pages in total, just generate those two urls with paste0.

Comment: I'm extremely confused as well. there's no print statement after  `firstPage  <- getPageNumber(URL)` . Would you be able to test out my program if were to post it full on pastebin. because maybe it has something to do with my workspace in Rstudio?

Comment: Last night the program ran with no bugs and this morning it wasn't  working

Comment: I'm suggesting you add a print statement to print out value of firstPage. Also, check the response code of the request. Are you blocked? It is getting late here now so I wouldn't be looking much at code for the rest of the night.

Comment: No problem I'll keep trying just very strange that my program stopped working overnight